# Best way to Manage Dynamic Json data from Facebook Graph api

Tags: c#, json, class, facebook-graph-api

I am starting to use the Facebook Graph API, but I readed that the variables constantly changes their names or been deprecated.
So, if create a Class to work with the results and the name of some variable changes, will get a error or stay without the value.
So, what´s the best way to work with that ?

Comment: just check out the changelog once in a while, and adapt to the changes...variable name changes do not happen that often.

Comment: Renaming or removing of fields usually only happens with new API versions. So as long as you version your API calls, you can be largely sure that such changes will not break your app. You will however have to modify your code, when an API version gets shut down and you need to use the next higher API version that has a feature/field removed. Sometimes features are removed for all existing API versions though (f.e. if they create a negative user experience or are used to spam) - in such cases, Facebook can’t let those features fade out over the next year or so, but has to take action promptly.

Comment: To keep yourself up-to-date with the relevant announcements etc., https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/ offers options to subscribe to different sources.

Comment: Thanks for the replys... This i already know... My doubt is if have some precaucion to take when construct the Class...something more dynamic... But thank you all.